# Getting duplicate messages with React + Socket.IO chat app

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

Attempting to create a simple React chat app, but I'm running into an issue where duplicate messages appear.  I run the server with `node server.js`, in a separate terminal run the client with `npm start`, then open two windows at `localhost:3000`.  I can send a message, but any message I send is received x2.  For example (after submitting the form with "i only sent this once" on one window, this is what appears in the second window).:

[image]

I did console.log on the server-side, and only one message is being received from the server.

Here is my `server.js` file:

```
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

app.use(cors());

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("connection", () => {});
  socket.on("send-message", (message) => {
    console.log(message);
    socket.broadcast.emit("message", message);
  });
});
```

Here's my `socket.js` file:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

const SERVER = "http://127.0.0.1:5001";

const connectionOptions = {
  forceNew: true,
  reconnectionAttempts: "Infinity",
  timeout: 10000,
  transports: ["websocket"],
};

let socket = io.connect(SERVER, connectionOptions);

export default socket;
```

Here's my `App.js` file:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import socket from "./socket";

const ChatWindow = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const handleMessageChange = (event) => {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("send-message", { message: message });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connection", null);
    socket.on("message", (payload) => {
      setMessages((prev) => {
        return [...prev, payload.message];
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map((message) => {
        return <h3>message: {message}</h3>;
      })}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input value={message} onChange={handleMessageChange}></input>
        <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
      </form>

      <h1>Chat Window</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChatWindow />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I really can't see why, but try removing the event listener for socket event on useEffects clean up function. there might be a chance that you are somehow subscribing twice.

Comment: and maybe try another name than `message`. socket-io might be using that name for some default behavior

Answer (score 3):

If you are using UseEffects Hooks you need to [clean up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect)

Before :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connection", null);
    socket.on("message", (payload) => {
      setMessages((prev) => {
        return [...prev, payload.message];
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

You can add this line to clean up :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connection", null);
    socket.on("message", (payload) => {
      setMessages((prev) => {
        return [...prev, payload.message];
      });
    });

    return () => socket.off("message"); // add this line to your code
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

As punjira answered in a comment, removing the event listener for the useEffect worked.

Specifically, before:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connection", null);
    socket.on("message", (payload) => {
      setMessages((prev) => {
        return [...prev, payload.message];
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

After:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connection", null);
    socket.on("msg", (payload) => {
      setMessages((prev) => {
        return [...prev, payload.msg];
      });
    });
    return function cleanup() {
      socket.removeListener("msg");
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if in index.js file the App is wrapped in React.StrictMode because it will cause the repetition.

Before:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

After:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

It worked for me

Comment: worked for me as well. Thanks! What might be causing this, any idea?